# Python FastApi Docker Image Can't open lib 'SQL Server'

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, fastapi

I use following code to connect with MSSQL. When I run this code on my local works without error. I tried to run this code as a docker container but it gives this error "sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") "

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker
import os

username = os.getenv("DB_USERNAME", "sa")
password = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD","Password")
server = os.getenv("DB_SERVER", "localhost")
database = os.getenv("DB_DATABASE", "master")
conn = "mssql+pyodbc://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server + "/" + database
print(username)
print(server)
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = (
    conn +
    "?driver=SQL+Server"
)

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,   
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Also my dockerfile:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install gcc
RUN apt-get -y install g++
RUN apt-get -y install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get clean

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV DB_USERNAME="sa"
ENV DB_PASSWORD="Password"
ENV DB_SERVER="localhost"
ENV DB_DATABASE="master"

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Comment: So where exactly are you installing the msodbc drivers to access SQL Server? If you `docker run -it --rm python:3.8-slim cat /etc/os-release` you can see that the image is using Debian 11 Bullseye. Have you read through the Debian sections of Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux) yet to install one of [msodbc17](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#debian17) or [msodbc18](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#debian18)?